# How to hide a players character locally only and not replicate on server

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

Inside the character blueprint, on the `Spring Arm Component` I added a `Box Collision` set to `OverlapOnlyPawn`, and when a character overlaps with it I'm calling `Set Actor Hidden In Game` to true, and when the overlaps ends to false, but the problem is that it is replicated automatically and so that character disappears for everyone and not just for the player that calls the function. I know that even if you call that function they still have collision and that is fine because I want to keep it, I only want that character skeletal mesh to disappear, make it invisible, like I said, only on the player side that calls the function.

Is there a way to achieve that? Maybe with a different function.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ u can use `Actor->RootComponent->SetHiddenInGame`.
This one changes `bHiddenInGame` field, so it will not replicate.

Comment: I'm in blueprint, but I can add a C++ function, the project is already hybrid, but I don't have UE classes inside the C++, only some pure C++ functions, and so I don't know what to write inside it. :) If that works it would be amazing, because what you say it is a bool, so I can easily reverse it when needed. And the function would have 2 parameters, the Actor and a bool to hide/show. I'm from Java background and I kinda get lost in all that when to use * and not, or &. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn the actor on your client, set the Owner field to your Player Controller.

With the Owner set to the local Player Controller, you can use the “Owner No See” and “Only Owner See” checkmarks on any Primitive Component (Static Mesh, Skeletal Mesh, etc.) that you need.

These settings can also be changed in Blueprint dynamically, so you can turn the visibility on/off at any point, using [this node](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/SetOnlyOwnerSee/).

For more info see [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/make-actor-only-visible-to-certain-players/56828/2).